# XBOX App not working on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, xbox-one

Sorry if this is a bit technical, I posted it earlier on MS support forums but they weren't helpful so I'm hoping if someone here had the same issue and was able to fix it.
I got my free Windows 10 upgrade yesterday and it installed with no errors or issues. Everything works fine, all devices have their drivers installed, I did not install any additional driver or application since I upgraded yesterday. The issue is with the new Xbox app, when I try to run it it pops up for a second and crashes. I found the following error in Windows event viewer:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Immersive-Shell
Date:          7/30/2015 6:07:29 PM
Event ID:      5973
Task Category: (5973)
Level:         Error
Keywords:      
User:          ZAID-HOME-PC\Zaid
Computer:      Zaid-Home-PC
Description:
Activation of app Microsoft.XboxApp_8wekyb3d8bbwe!Microsoft.XboxApp failed with error: The app didn't start. See the Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational log for additional information.
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Immersive-Shell" Guid="{315A8872-923E-4EA2-9889-33CD4754BF64}" />
    <EventID>5973</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>5973</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x2000000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-07-30T15:07:29.767631500Z" />
    <EventRecordID>656</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="4288" ThreadID="2736" />
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>Zaid-Home-PC</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-21-1677041472-2942404152-2187633501-1001" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="AppId">Microsoft.XboxApp_8wekyb3d8bbwe!Microsoft.XboxApp</Data>
    <Data Name="ErrorCode">-2144927141</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

All other applications desktop and modern style work fine except for Xbox. I then went and opened the store to see if there is any update available for it and indeed there was an update yet it failed to install. There is a message that says (Try that again) and a see details link next to it. Viewing the details shows the following message:

```
Try that again
Something went wrong
The error code is 0x80073B0F, in case you need it.
```

MS support suggest I turn off my anti-virus (Windows Defender) and do a wsreset so I did but it did not help
Can someone tell me how to fix this.

My basic device information:

```
Toshiba Satellite L500
Intel Core i3 M330 @ 2.13 GHz
8GB DDR3 Ram
ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4500
```

Comment: Have you ran the DISM and SFC tools?

Comment: @Ramhound I ran SFC and it did not detect any issues. Did not do DISM though, what options should I use?

Comment: `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth`

Comment: @Ramhound still the same issue after dism

Comment: Information about your system might be helpful.  You are going to have to figure out or provide more information, on the reason, you cannot update the application.

Comment: @Ramhound I updated the question with my basic device information. Let me know if you need any other info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems not many people are having this exact issue. I've come back to your post many times just to see if there was an update. I found the solution for this issue. You'll have to be patient while it completes. It keeps you from wiping your rig though.

http://winsupersite.com/windows-10/fixing-windows-10-apps-wont-launch-or-hang-apps-splash-screen

> The potential fix goes back to similar issues experienced during earlier Builds, which includes executing a PowerShell command at an elevated command prompt.
>
> The PowerShell command:
>
> `Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}`

Hopefully this also works for you!

Comment: WOW!!!! thank you so so much this worked for me.....

Answer (score 1):

Only Microsoft support is going to provide an official supported answer on such a new release and issue. I found the following resource to be the most relevant to your situation by referencing the error code(s) found within your event log transcript: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_desktop/build-9926-most-of-modern-ui-not-working/d87e1903-661d-48b2-b2eb-41c0ab615d55

By the end of it, users reported that despite the suggested fixes, only re-installing really got them back into a working state. Inevitably the next header...

---

### Re-installing Windows 10

1. Open: PC Settings
2. Select: Update and recovery
3. Select: Recovery
4. Click: Get started, follow prompts

---

Sucks, and probably isn't the answer you're looking to find. The reality is that the software has just been released, and that now-a-days it's easier to update as time goes on versus ensuring normal operation out of the gate. Alternatively, you can wait for an update that could patch this.

I upgraded to $LINUX_FLAVOR instead. :-)

Comment: I asked here just to see if someone else had the issue and was able to fix it. I don't see how the link you posted can help me or how it is related to this issue. Moreover I don't see how DOWNGRADING to linux can help ;)